# Check if skype name exists

Tags: vb.net, skype

I'm making a program which will check if a skype name exists with other features. I just can't find a way to check if the skype name exists to continue.

If it does then it goes into a procedure which I have set up, if it doesn't a MsgBox() appears saying the skype name doesn't exist. If anyone knows of a way to do please reply, I don't mind if its built in code or if its using a web browser to check if a skype account exists then does the code required.

I haven't tried anything in VB other than finding sites saying if a skype username is online or offline (mystatus.skype.com/) but that doesn't seem to be working, and I tried using the Skype avatar link, but even if the account doesn't exist then it will show the default skype account picture.

If this is impossible, please tell me.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks to Plutonix for adding the Skype tag :)